# JLabel is transparent while opening file

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I've programmed a tool that opens and parses files. As this is taking some time, I wanted to make a little status window, by now it's just consisting of a JLable with the text "Import running, please wait...".
However, during runtime it looks like this:
[image: Transparent JLabel]

After the file import is finished, the window is fine, showing the text and everything. I tried programming it without Threads at first, then I thought maybe making it multithreaded will help. So I made the window open in it's own Thread, the file import in it's own Thread and finally both in their own Thread. The result still was the same.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Importing file, please wait...");
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(100, 100);
frame.add((new JPanel()).add(label));
//no difference to frame.add(label);
frame.setVisible(true);
//Parse File
openParseFile();
//Close status window after parsing complete
frame.dispose();
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this? I tried googleing it, but the results only showed how to make a JLapel transparent, not the other way around.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks
Sverre

Comment: You've blocked the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing from processing any new events, including paint requests.  Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: *"So I made the window open in it's own Thread"* - That's not how it works.  All Swing components operate within a single thread of their own, the EDT.  You need to move your processing out to a different thread.  You could use something like `SwingWorker` which can provide mechanisms to tell you when the worker is done

Comment: This seems to be working, thanks for the advice. I'll post my solution later here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution, thanks to the comment of MadProgrammer and this tutorial: [Javacreed SwingWorker Examle](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Importing file, please wait...");
status  = new JFrame();
status.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
status.setSize(100, 100);
status.add((new JPanel()).add(label));
status.setVisible(true);
SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            openTableReader();


            return null;
        }

    };
    sw.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (event.getPropertyName().equals("state") && ((StateValue)event.getNewValue()).equals(StateValue.DONE)) {
                processResult();
                status.dispose();
            }
        }

    }) ;
    sw.execute();
```